# The site groups.google.com does not list any groups I am a member of, on Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups

### Issue

While I'm logged in to google.com with my Workspace account, where my account belongs to multiple groups (verified as an admin on [admin.google.com/u/3/ac/groups](https://admin.google.com/u/3/ac/groups)), I do not see any of those groups on https://groups.google.com/u/3/, the page that I'm taken to when I click "Groups" button in the 9 dot menu on the top-right on my Workspace pages.

### Attempted but didn't seem to resolve the issue

- I saw the 10 year old post [Where can I see the groups I am a member of in my enterprise account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/46711) that suggests that I should be able to see the list of groups I'm in, but that's not what I'm seeing.
- From the admin console, I created a test group that my account is an owner of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On admin console, Apps->Google Workspace->Settings for Groups for Business->Service Status (something like https://admin.google.com/u/3/ac/settings/serviceonoff?iid=15&aid=OUR_OWN_ID), "Off for everyone" was selected so I checked "On for everyone", waited for 10 or so minutes. Then the expected groups showed up under https://groups.google.com/u/3/all-groups.